# sed search pattern with variable name and comment it

Tags: regex, sed

I have file which contains lines like below,

```
target          /test/purpose/for/firstunit chapter
target      /test/purpose/for/firstunit chapter
```

I assigned variable,

```
i="/test/purpose/for/firstunit"
```

and trying to comment the lines which contains this variable value

```
sed -i "/\$i/s/^/#/g" file_name
```

but its not working. not sure what am missing here.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed -i "s:.*$i:#&:" file_name
```

Adds a leading `#` to lines containing the `$i` value.

Answer (score 1):

Since the pattern you are using contains slashes `/`, the sed command gets too many slashes overall.

Thus, it is just a matter of using another delimiter, for example `_`:

```
sed "\_${i}_s_^_\#_g" file
```

Let's test it:

```
$ cat f
target          /test/purpose/for/firstunit chapter
target      /test/purpose/for/firstunit chapter
dad
$ sed "\_${i}_s_^_\#_g" f
#target          /test/purpose/for/firstunit chapter
#target      /test/purpose/for/firstunit chapter
dad
```

Comment: Hmmm still getting below error 

`sed: -e expression #1, char 53: expected newer version of sed`